# Code::Blocks says icon.res not found on linux

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

I am trying to add an icon to a c++ program in code::blocks by adding the "icon.rc" file which worked on windows but now that I'm doing it on Linux the build log say it needs a file called "icon.res" in the "obj/Debug" folder.
Help?

this is supposed to add an icon to the final executable but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Windows and Linux are two completely different operating systems and application icons are *highly* OS-specific. Additionally on Linux it also depends on which Desktop Environment you use

Comment: The problem is not the icon file. It is the _resource_ file which is causing problems.

Comment: That's probably because your build script is trying to link "icon.res" to the final executable - it probably wasn't created because there is no program on Linux that would convert a ".rc" file into a ".res" file (as neither of them are used in Linux desktop environments)

Comment: I actually did try to add a file named "icon.res" to the "obj/Debug" folder but then it says that ld returned 1 exit status.

Comment: That's not surprising, GCCs linker has no notion of a ".res" file, so it doesn't know what to do with it and errors out instead

Comment: then why does it say it needs a .res file in the first place?

Comment: Read my second comment again

Comment: So then why is it trying to link the nonexistent "icon.res" to the executable?

Comment: Because your build script is telling it to do that. There is no "magic" that would tell a compiler or linker to put things together otherwise

Comment: How do I fix the build script then?